# sorting through lists of lists to find shared variants

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics

I have a list of lists called `allLinesList`, each line of `allLinesList` contains four lists. Here are two lines from `allLinesList`

```
[[['ACmerged_contig_10464', '668', '.', 'A', 'G', '3.87133', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=0;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=28', 'GT:PL', '0/0:28,3,0'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '668', '.', 'A', 'G', '3.87133', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=0;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=28', 'GT:PL', '0/0:28,3,0'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '747', '.', 'T', '.', '84', '.', 'DP=2;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,2,0,0;MQ=32', 'GT', '0/0'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '747', '.', 'T', '.', '84', '.', 'DP=2;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,2,0,0;MQ=32', 'GT', '0/0']],
[['ACmerged_contig_10464', '4', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '4', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '4', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '4', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.']]]
```

There are a couple of thousand lines total in `allLinesList`.

I want to go through all these lines in `allLinesList`, and pick out lines where specific inner lists share the same character as their 5th item, as long as the character is not a `'.'`. Once I have identified lines like this, I will put the first item of that line into a separate list.

For example, in the first list above, the first two inner lists share `'G'` as their 5th item. Hence I would want to output one of these lists to a different list. This would create another list of lists, but one only with two layers of lists, not three layers of lists like my example.

I have code that works to do this, but I think there must be a more efficient way of doing this, maybe using a loop, that I haven't figured out. Here is my current code:

```
sharedLists1_2 = []
i = 0
while i < len(allLinesList):
    if allLinesList[i][0][4] != "." and allLinesList[i][0][4] == allLinesList[i][1][4] and allLinesList[i][1][4] != allLinesList[i][2][4] and allLinesList[i][1][4] != allLinesList[i][3][4]:
        sharedLists1_2.append(allLinesList[i][1])
    i +=1
```

At the moment, I am running a version of this code 6 times, to get all the pairwise combinations for the four items in my list ((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (1,4), (1,3), (2,4)).

How can I get the same result but in a more efficient way that doesn't involve me putting in this block of code, but with different numbers, 6 times?

Comment: In `[['ACmerged_contig_10464', '2', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '2', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '2', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.'], ['ACmerged_contig_10464', '2', '.', 'T', '.', '29.5864', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=0;DP4=0,0,0,0;MQ=.', 'GT', './.']]`, per example, what is the 5th item ?

Comment: Your description of which combinations you want to check is unclear. In your code, you're checking items from different inner lists.

Comment: @codrelphi The fifth item of all the innermost lists is `'.'`

Comment: @slider I have updated my text, maybe this provides more clarification. I am indeed checking between items from different inner lists, but in the end I only want to output one of the inner lists. What do you need more clarification on?

Comment: @wilberox: the code you gave to us is not working. Check it!

Comment: @codrelphi The code is definitely working for me. Perhaps I was not clear about the levels of nested lists in `allLinesList`. I have added extra square brackets for clarity. Does this work for you?

Comment: Still not working!

Comment: @codrelphi It's working for me

Comment: @codrelphi comma between two first level nested lists was missing. Should function.

Comment: Yes, now it's working. I get this result: `[['ACmerged_contig_10464', '668', '.', 'A', 'G', '3.87133', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=0;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=28', 'GT:PL', '0/0:28,3,0']]`.

Comment: This part `At the moment, I am running a version of this code 6 times, to get all the pairwise combinations for the four items in my list ((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (1,4), (1,3), (2,4)).` is really unclear for me.

Comment: @codrelphi yes that is the intended result

Comment: @codrelphi I need to get combinations for variants found in the first and second lists, but not the third and fourth lists, variants found in the second and third list, but not the first and fourth, variants found in the third and fourth list, but not the first and second, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Iterate through all the 2 element combinations and check for your condition. If it matches, you can append the result to a dictionary that stores results for each index pair

To check that the value is not the same for the remaining lists (other than `i`, `j` for a given combination), you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) while iterating through a remaining indices:

```
from itertools import combinations

shared_lists = {}    

for line in allLinesList:
    indices = set(range(len(line)))
    for i, j in combinations(range(len(line)), 2):
        remaining = indices - {i, j}
        if line[i][4] != "." and line[i][4] == line[j][4] and all(line[i][4] != line[x][4] for x in remaining):
            shared_lists.setdefault((i, j), []).append(line[j])

print(shared_lists)
```

**Output**

```
{(0, 1): [['ACmerged_contig_10464', '668', '.', 'A', 'G', '3.87133', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=0;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=28', 'GT:PL', '0/0:28,3,0']]}
```

Comment: I don't think this works completely: when I print `shared_lists.keys()` It shows that there are only two combinations: `[(0, 1), (2, 3)]`. I need six: '[(0, 1), (2, 3), (0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 3), (1, 2)]

Comment: @wilberox It means the condition was met for only those combinations. But it does run for all six combinations. You can add a `print` statement inside the for loop to print `i`, `j` to verify.

Comment: If I wanted to check for similarities between sets of three lists, would I use `from itertools import combinations

shared_lists = {}    

for line in allLinesList:
    indices = set(range(len(line)))
    for i, j in combinations(range(len(line)), 3):
        remaining = indices - {i, j}
        if line[i][4] != "." and line[i][4] == line[j][4] and all(line[i][4] != line[x][4] for x in remaining):
            shared_lists.setdefault((i, j), []).append(line[j])

print(shared_lists)`? i.e. change the `2` in the 7th line to a `3`?

Comment: @wilberox For 3-element combinations, you would probably need something like `for i, j, k in combinations(range(len(line)), 3)` because the tuple would be of size 3. Similarly, `remaining` would have to be `remaining = indices - {i, j, k}` and your `if` condition would have to check for `line[k]` as well. A better approach would be to use `all` for the positive check as well.

Comment: yes I believe I have managed to do something similar to that now, thank you for the very good help.